# Session TimeOut MVC 5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

Estou tentando implementar o Timeout Session em uma aplicação MVC5.

Estou com a seguinte string no Web.config:

```
<sessionState mode="InProc" cookieless="true" timeout="15" />
```

Criei a classe :

```
public class SessionExpireAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        HttpContext ctx = HttpContext.Current;
        // check  sessions here
        if( HttpContext.Current.Session["username"] == null ) 
        {
           filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult("~/Home/Index");
           return;
        }
        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
    }
}
```

Acrescentei a Tag à classe:

```
[SessionExpire]
public class HomeController : Controller
{
  public ActionResult Index()
  {
     return Index();
  }
}
```

Na action de login eu acrescentei:

```
Session["username"] = usuario.UserName;
```

O problema ocorre quando executa o código :

```
if( HttpContext.Current.Session["username"] == null ) 
        {
           filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult("~/Home/Index");
           return;
        }
```

Este código sempre apresenta null para HttpContext.Current.Session["username"]

Comment: Só uma dúvida (não tem a ver com a questão da session aí), mas você está utilizando o ASP.NET Identity? Ele tem mecanismos prontos para cuidar disso para você.

Comment: Na verdade eu quero tratar do Session. Tenho requisições que quero tratar depois de um tempo de inativatividade. São requisições que são feitas via Jquery utilizando ajax. Aí se tiver passado um tempo sem que o usuário tenha alguma atividade, quero forçar um novo login.

Answer (score 0):

Estou com o mesmo problema, quando executo o comando sempre retorna NULL

 `private ObjX Entidade = new ObjX();
 Entidade = (ObjX)Session["SessaoObj"];`